# Modern temperature compensation of 1 V/oct VCOs

Tags: transistors, frequency, vco, synthesizer, scaling

With Akaneohm Tempco resistors going out of production, I have been searching for alternative ways to reliably build a VCO that does not drift with temperature. I have been searching around, but I can only find good information on older VCO designs from Moog and Buchla that rely on these tempco resistors to compensate for the change in saturation current (as a result of temperature change) of the BJT pair used to make up the exponential V-I converter.

I know there are platinum SMT tempco resistors available, but they are not close enough to the ideal values to ensure a proper scaling factor for 1V/oct.

To be clear, when I refer to a tempco resistor, I mean a resistor that has had its properties designed to change in a predictable way with temperature. For example, the resistor for the Buchla 259 triangle core oscillator is a 2k positive temperature coefficient (PTC) at 3300ppm. The platinum smt sensors, as they call them, are rated at 3850ppm. Thermistors have a much higher variation of resistance and are not suited for this application as far as I am aware.

How do I design a modern 1V/oct VCO design or know of any good methods to compensate for temperature in an exponential voltage to current converter?

Comment: What are you referring to as a "tempco resistor"? A tempco is a property of a resistor, not a type of resistor.

Comment: Have you considered a series and/or parallel arrangement of low TC resistors with the  Pt device?

Comment: Its unfortunate, but the standard modern way would be to use a crystal (<100ppm temperature coefficients are normal), microcontroller, precision ADC and DAC for DDS.